# flex ios cameraroll can't get image content?

Tags: ios, apache-flex

about my APP,
I want to take a picture and upload to server.
I had reference to this article: [Uploading images from CameraRoll and CameraUI](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/uploading-images-media-promise.html),but I can't get the picture content in following code block:

```
private function readMediaData():void
{
    var imageBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    dataSource.readBytes( imageBytes );
    ......
}
```

imageBytes will be 0 KB,
anyone knows why?
thanks~

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow; I strongly suggest you try to provide as many details as possible.  We do not want to read an external tutorial in order to help understand your code.  After this question I may ask "What is type of the dataSource variable"?  What makes you think that imageBytes() should have a value, based on the code you've provided?

Answer (score 0):

I was solving exactly the same issue. It looks like there is some bug (or is this some kind of "undocumented feature"?) in Air.

The problem seems to be that as soon as you load the image using loadFilePromise() you 'lose' the data source, so the IDataInput will always return its length as 0 and nothing will be read into the byte array. This happens ONLY on iOS, it works fine on Android. What you need to do is edit your event handler:

```
private function onMediaPromiseLoaded(event:Event):void{
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onMediaPromiseLoaded);
    bytes = new ByteArray(); //this is an instance variable
    dataSource.readBytes(bytes); //read the bytes into it BEFORE doing anything else
    //do the rest of the stuff, load picture and add to gallery or whatever
}
```

It is working for me and I hope this will help to somebody.